# wxWIDGETS IN C++ Errors In The Program-Edited

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

I have the following code and i am programming in c++ :-
I followed the instructions given here by the members and changed the code as :-

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <wx/thread.h>
 #include <wx/log.h>
 #include <wx/app.h>

 using namespace std;


 class MyThread;

 class MyThread : public wxThread {
 public:

 MyThread(unsigned int& c);

 virtual ~MyThread();

 wxThreadError Create(unsigned int stackSize = 0);
 wxThreadError Run();
 wxThreadError Delete(ExitCode* rc = NULL, wxThreadWait waitMode =    
 wxTHREAD_WAIT_BLOCK);
 virtual ExitCode Entry();

 private:

 unsigned int& counter;
 };
 MyThread::MyThread(unsigned int& c)
 {
 counter = c;
 }
 MyThread::~MyThread()
 {

 }

 wxThread::ExitCode MyThread::Entry()
 {
 while(counter < 0xFFFFFFFF)
    ++counter;
 return 0;

 }
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 unsigned int uiCounter = 0;

 MyThread *mt = new MyThread(unsigned int&);
 if (mt) {
     if (mt->MyThread::Create() == wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
        if (mt->MyThread::Run() == wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {

        }
    }
    mt->Delete();
 }
 char cChar = ' ';
 while (cChar != 'q') {
    cout << uiCounter<< endl;
    cChar = (char) getchar();
  }
 return 0;
  }
```

And have faced the dollowing errors now

```
 newmain.cpp: In constructor 'MyThread::MyThread(unsigned int&)':
 newmain.cpp:38:1: error: uninitialized reference member 'MyThread::counter' [-   
 fpermissive]

 newmain.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
 newmain.cpp:57:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'
```

In this problem what i am doing is that i have got two threads one is the main() and other one i have derived from wxthread

Comment: there are many things wrong with this code. I suggest you start with something simpler. If you have questions I suggest looking here first : http://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Try the thread example provided by wxWidgets: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/thread/thread.cpp?revision=70412&view=markup

Comment: The thread sample more or less is related to the GUI programming , i want to learn a simple thread creation as per the scenario

Comment: Have you read the message from the compiler?  It is telling you what the problem is.  You can do what it says: initialise the counter reference in the constructor.  The compiler error will then go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler messages tell you how to remove the errors.  Start at the top and tackle them one by one.

```
newmain.cpp:23:25: error: 'Entry' declared as a 'virtual' field
```

so the error is in this line

```
virtual void *Entry(LPVOID param);
```

Take a look at the definition of wxThread::Entry() which can be found here http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxthread.html#wxthreadentry

You will see immediately that the base method has a return value and no parameters.  The function you create to override the base method must do the same.